# mono compiler mcs does not compile some methods or property but it execute the compiled visual studio exe fine

Tags: mono

Is there is any problem with mono Compiler mcs as when I compile this code with mcs compiler(with command mono Program.cs) it gives error unexpected symbol 'var'

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object o = "test";
        var s = o;
        if (s.GetType() == typeof (string))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fails ");
        }
    }
}
```

but if I execute this program exe , compiled in visual studio direct in linux with command

mono Program.exe

its gives result ok without any error..

Please give the reason for this...

Comment: Could you please review the formatting of your question? It's hardly readable. Make sure to use code tags on your code lines or anything you would like to highlight. Making a question easily readable is the first step to get a clear answer :)

Comment: `with command mono Program.cs` - surely you mean `mcs Program.cs`, right? Also, you are missing `using System;`. Other than that, it compiles fine. Also give your mcs version, and make sure you are using at least c# 3.0 language. In some earlier versions you might need to use `gmcs` or `dmcs`.